# Ansible: how to store all hosts affected by a task in a variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I have a playbook that targets a small set of hosts, and a task there that changes some configuration files on one or more of these hosts, depending on how I've set my variables.

A simplified example result of running this task:

```
TASK [somerole : create config file] *************************************
ok: [server1] => (item=foo.conf)
changed: [server2] => (item=foo.conf)
changed: [server3] => (item=foo.conf)
```

If I use `register` on this task and then `debug` the variable it creates, the output of the `debug: var=varname` would look something like this (considerably simplified):

```
TASK [somerole : debug] **************************************************
ok: [server1] => {
    "varname": {
        "changed": false,
        "results": [{...}]
    }
}
ok: [server2] => {
    "varname": {
        "changed": true,
        "results": [{...}]
    }
}
ok: [server3] => {
    "varname": {
        "changed": true,
        "results": [{...}]
    }
}
```

The config change necessitates a service restart that currently has to be done manually by a human (there's a manual eyeballing validation step). To help with this, I would like to use the `pause` module at the end of the playbook to display a prompt to the user, looking something like this:

```
- pause:
    prompt: |-
      The configuration has changed on the following servers: {{ changed_servers|join(', ' }}

      Please restart service X on these servers after validating Y and Z.
```

So, how do I build the `changed_servers` variable? Given the examples above, it would be this list:`["server2", "server3"]` (since they were the hosts changed by the task this time).

I first thought I'd try to combine the `varname` variable that `register` produced for each host affected by the task, looking at the `changed` boolean in each, but the name of the host is not present anywhere inside `varname` so that I could combine the `changed` attribute with the name of the corresponding host.

Is there actually a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: *"**Store all hosts affected by a task in a variable*"**

A: Register a variable with the result of the task. Then use [extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) to collect the results. For example, the playbook below creates the file *foo.conf* registers the result and creates the dictionary `dict_foo_conf`

```yaml
- hosts: test_11,test_12,test_13
  tasks:
    - command:
        cmd: touch foo.conf
        creates: foo.conf
        warn: false
      register: result_foo_conf
    - set_fact:
        dict_foo_conf: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts_all|zip(my_results)) }}"
      vars:
        my_results: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                        map('extract', hostvars, ['result_foo_conf', 'changed'])|
                        list }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [command] *************************************************************
changed: [test_11]
changed: [test_12]
changed: [test_13]
```

```yaml
  dict_foo_conf:
    test_11: true
    test_12: true
    test_13: true
```

---

There are no changes when you run the playbook again

```yaml
TASK [command] ******************************************************************
ok: [test_13]
ok: [test_11]
ok: [test_12]
```

```yaml
  dict_foo_conf:
    test_11: false
    test_12: false
    test_13: false
```

---

Let's remove the files from hosts test_12 and test_13

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_12 rm foo.conf
shell> ssh admin@test_13 rm foo.conf
```

The playbook gives

```yaml
TASK [command] ******************************************************************
changed: [test_12]
ok: [test_11]
changed: [test_13]
```

```yaml
  dict_foo_conf:
    test_11: false
    test_12: true
    test_13: true
```

Then select hosts that changed, for example

```yaml
  - set_fact:
      changed_hosts: "{{ dict_foo_conf|dict2items|json_query('[?value].key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  changed_hosts:
  - test_12
  - test_13
```

Comment: Ooh, that's clever. Nice one!